# MPVideoPlayer add/remove buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

Does anyone knows how to add/remove buttons from the MPVideoPlayer window?

I put bellow an example form an app that does that. It is in App Store which means that it is allowed by Apple.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** I think that the main way to do it is just by obtaining the `UITabBarController` of the `MPVideoPlayer window`.

[Example http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/5184/poz.jpg](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/5184/poz.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the keywindow then u can find the view ..... so u could be access the button of the view ..

Comment: I was unable to access buttons, did you achieve this ?

Comment: hi,maybe the 'UITabBarController' also can do the same job , but I have not test it . 

 as I think that you can find the window of the player then you can access the subview of the window.... of course ,you need use recurring for each view and subview ,or else you only can find the root level views....